# Regular expression in java? I'm stuck

Tags: java, regex

I got some text that changes dynamically and I need a way to find some parts in it.
Especially like these:

+124now

+78now

+45now

So my values always starts with an "+" plus symbol then some digits, minimum one and then the "now" word.

I tried many ways like this:

```
if(myString.contains("+[0-9]+now")) //false
```

but I tired of it... can you help please?

Comment: `String#contains` takes a string as a parameter, not a regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this......

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\+\\d+now");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher("Input_Text");

while(mat.find()){

   // Do whatever you want to do with the data now...

 }
```

Comment: yup..... thats right.... mat.group() or mat.group(0) both will do here.... i just left it to OP

Comment: true mat.group() returns mat.group(0) :)

Answer (score 9):

Use [`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) instead:

```
if (myString.matches(".*\\+[0-9]+now.*"))
```

Also, `+` is a special regex character, that's why you need to escape it.

If you need to *capture* the numbers, use [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\+([0-9]+)now");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

`()` is a capturing group, meaning it will tell the regex engine to *store* the matched content, so that you can retrieve it later with [`group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29).

Comment: OP asks about a part of the string, not the whole string

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the first '+' like this:

```
if(myString.matches("\\+[0-9]+now"));
```

The + means "literally find a + in the string" instead of "find this character 1 or more times"

Comment: `String#contains` takes a string as a parameter, not a regex.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you would like to either match the string or else maybe extract the digits in the middle? In yout case, the problem is that the `+` us a special character, thus you need to escape it like so: `\\+`, so your regex becomes `\\+[0-9]+now`.

As for your second problem, the `.contains` method takes a string, not a regular expression, so your code will not work.

```
    String str = "+124now";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\+(\\d+)now");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    while (m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));         
    }
```

In this case, I have extracted the digits just in case this is something you are after.

Answer (score 1):

The method `contains` does not interpret its argument as a regular expression. Use the method `matches` instead. You have to escape the `+` as well, like this:

```
if (myString.matches("\\+\\d+now"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said the string always starts with `+` and always ends with `now` why not check that  this is true. If not then something is wrong.

```
    String[] vals = {"+124now", "+78now", "-124now", "+124new"};

    for (String s : vals) {
        if (s.matches("^\\+(\\d+)now$")) {
            System.out.println(s + " matches.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(s + " does not match.");
        }
    }
```

Of course, if you want to capture the number then use a matcher like npinti suggests.

EDIT:
Here's how to get the number:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\+(\\d+)now$");
    for (String s : vals) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(s + " matches and the number is: " + m.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println(s + " does not match.");
        }
    }
```